# XSL Traverse similar grandchildren of non similar parents and update

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have my xml such that I would like to get the tagname and segnum only when the other children are not blank or null values, when other segments are null I do not want to leave as blank in the output.

to get tagname I am using  within a for-each, and to get the segnum I am using "count(preceding::head) + 1", however I do not know how to exclude the blank tags

```
<myxml>
  <a>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
      <segnum></segnum>
    </head>
    <fs>axl</fs>
    <es>hoot</es>
  </a>
  <b>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
      <segnum></segnum>
    </head>
    <zz>suger</zz>
    <sd>mint</sd>
  </b>
  <b>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
    </head>
    <zz></zz>
    <sd></sd>
    <gs></gs>
  </b>
  <g>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
      <segnum></segnum>
    </head>
    <gz></gz>
    <gd></gd>
    <gs></gs>
  </g>
</myxml>

required output:

<myxml>
  <a>
    <head>
      <tagname>a</tagname>
      <segnum>1</segnum>
    </head>
    <fs>axl</fs>
    <es>hoot</es>
  </a>
  <b>
    <head>
      <tagname>b</tagname>
      <segnum>2</segnum>
    </head>
    <zz>suger</zz>
    <sd>mint</sd>
  </b>
  <b>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
      <segnum></segnum>
    </head>
    <zz></zz>
    <sd></sd>
    <gs></gs>
  </b>
  <g>
    <head>
      <tagname></tagname>
      <segnum></segnum>
    </head>
    <gz></gz>
    <gd></gd>
    <gs></gs>
  </g>
</myxml>
```

Regards,

Comment: Two questions to clarify: (a) XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, (b) when an element has non-blank children, is the segnum based on all segments or only the non-blank ones? In other words, if there were another non-blank segment after the blank ones at the end of your example should it be numbered 5 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start off by having a template to match only **head** elements where the other children are not blank

```
<xsl:template match="head[following-sibling::*/text()]">
```

Then you can get the count of the number of preceding **head** elements by making use of **xsl:number** to do the counting

```
<xsl:variable name="count">
   <xsl:number count="head[following-sibling::*/text()]" level="any" />
</xsl:variable>
```

You could then output this in your **tagname** element like so:

```
<tagname><xsl:number value="$count" format="a" /></tagname>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="head[following-sibling::*/text()]">
      <xsl:variable name="count">
         <xsl:number count="head[following-sibling::*/text()]" level="any" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <head>
         <tagname><xsl:number value="$count" format="a"  /></tagname>
         <segnum><xsl:number value="$count" /></segnum>
      </head>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<myxml>
  <a>
    <head>
       <tagname>a</tagname>
       <segnum>1</segnum>
    </head>
    <fs>axl</fs>
    <es>hoot</es>
  </a>
  <b>
    <head>
       <tagname>b</tagname>
       <segnum>2</segnum>
    </head>
    <zz>suger</zz>
    <sd>mint</sd>
  </b>
  <b>
    <head>
      <tagname/>
    </head>
    <zz/>
    <sd/>
    <gs/>
  </b>
  <g>
    <head>
      <tagname/>
      <segnum/>
    </head>
    <gz/>
    <gd/>
    <gs/>
  </g>
</myxml>
```